# I dont' know how to install libXtst.so.6 library required for my application deployed on heroku

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, shared-libraries

I have made a spring-boot app printing some created files in Microsoft Word. Locally it works fine. However when i try to print them via an app deployed on heroku such a problem occurs:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500). /app/.jdk/jre/lib/amd64/libawt_xawt.so: libXtst.so.6:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

From what i looked up in google i believe i should install somewhere libxrender1:i386 libxtst6:i386 libxi6:i386. I just don't know where to find it and where exactly should i put it. I would be really happy if someone could help me sort this out.

Comment: Are you trying to print on the server?

Comment: I am trying to make an user to print the Word file created in the user computer (windows).

Answer (score 1):

> From what i looked up in google i believe i should install somewhere libxrender1:i386 libxtst6:i386 libxi6:i386.

That is *incorrect*: the reference to the `libXtst.so.6` comes from `.../jre/lib/amd64/libawt_xawt.so`, so you need a 64-bit version of `libXtst.so.6`, not a 32-bit one.

> I just don't know where to find it and where exactly should i put it.

The answer is: use package manager that comes with your system (you didn't tell us what OS you are running).

This could be `sudo apt install libxtst6` (Ubuntu / Debian), or `sudo yum install libXtst` (CentOS or RedHat or Fedora), or something else.

Comment: Solved, I was trying to make my application to create a file on users computers which is sth i obviously can't do, sorry for wasting your time and thanks!